# Jenkins Build not failing

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I'd like know what can makes Jenkins ignore a compilation error, and finish a job with a successful status?

We're using Jenkins v1.590 with Maven 1.0.2 (no choice for the moment) and SVN. Our project is a web application and it is subdivided into 5 Maven modules. 4 Java modules/projects that produce jars and 1 module that produces a war.

Here is an example of a compilation error that should fail with the build of the war:

```
C:\DevTools\workspace-Jenkins\xxxxx_Construction_du_War_3_18_x\src\main\java\com\.....\servlet\command\compte\RemboursementAnnuler.java:54: annulerReglement(com.........base.ReglementBean,java.lang.String,com.........securite.BusinessUtilisateurBean) in com......transaction.compte.Compte cannot be applied to (com......base.ReglementBean,com.......metier.securite.BusinessUtilisateurBean)
                : new Compte().annulerReglement(reglementBean, businessUtilisateurBean);
                                  ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors

BUILD FAILED
File...... C:\.maven\cache\maven-java-plugin-1.5\plugin.jelly
Element... ant:javac
Line...... 63
Column.... 48
Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Total time: 33 seconds
Finished at: Mon Nov 24 18:54:39 CET 2014

Finished: SUCCESS
```

Why Jenkins can't detect itself the failure ? Could it be something with the exit code of Maven 1?

I tried with one of the project that build a jar and it's the same problem.

Any clue?

Thank you by advance.

**[EDIT] My solution :**
Inspired by the suggestion from **@Jigar Joshi**, I just replaced the Maven build step by a simple batch command calling `maven clean ...` (because with Maven 1, by default the command name is `maven`, not `mvn`). I've done that in each one of my modules/jobs and now every compilation error is properly reported as a build failed. The problem was effectively the return code of the Maven command.

Before to be able to call `maven.bat` into a job, I had to install Maven 1.0.2 into a classic location (e.g. `c:\DevTools\maven-1.0.2`), set the `MAVEN_HOME` environment variable to point on that location and also added `%MAVEN_HOME%\bin` to `PATH` environment variable. Then I restarted the machine to let Jenkins take all that into account and now all is fine.

Comment: how is your jenkins project configured ?

Comment: What type of build step are you using - a Maven build step, or a shell / Windows batch step that calls mvn ?

Comment: @Jigar Joshi: What do you mean ? Anyway, I think I have a track... I've just seen into the help of the Maven targets (into the configuration of the Jenkins job) that some versions of Maven have a bad return code !! But it is not specified how to work around it...

Comment: just use free style project and configure bash to invoke maven command, it will work

Comment: @gareth_bowles: I'm using a Maven build. I have declared the Maven 1.0.2 configuration into Jenkins and I've created a job using Maven type.

Comment: @Jigar Joshi: ok that seems to be a good solution. Thank you. I'll test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the issue with jenkins maven plugin, I would rather setup free-style jenkins project and invoke `mvn` from bash directly that way exit status won't be an issue